# Why did the Red Queen only render Alice unconscious at the beginning?

Tags: resident-evil

Why did the Red Queen release knockout gas to Alice at the beginning of *Resident Evil* (2002)? Why not use a lethal gas?

OK, maybe humans designed the house, but the question still stands. What is the point of amnesing Alice in critical situation? Unfortunately the [FAQ at IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120804/faq#faq-answered) does not have an answer.

Comment: Could be as simple as lethal gas not being an available option in the mansion.  Or that her natural genetics give her a degree of immunity.  Remember that everyone else mutated when exposed to the T-Virus, but Alice did not.

Comment: @Tim was Alice indeed immune in the first movie? Also, her 'husband' did not die neither, and only got stuck in the train (unless he pretended so...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The house’s primary defenses have been activated. She’s probably still
>   suffering the side effects.

So the gas that was released was the primary defense, it would appear that was the best solution that the Red Queen had.

> The Hive has its own defense mechanisms are all computer controlled.
>   You and your partner were intended as the first line of defense in the
>   mansion. If you were killed or incapacitated, then the computer could
>   deploy its own defenses. A nerve agent released through hidden vents
>   in the house. Primary effect of the gas is complete unconsciousness,
>   lasting anything up to four hours. Secondary effects are varied, but
>   can include acute memory loss.

The fact was that there was an outbreak, so them being the first line of defense had failed so the computer used all primary defense mechanisms available, i don't believe it intentionally targeted Alice, but deploy all primary defenses to prevent an outbreak.

Comment: `i don't believe it intentionally targeted Alice` --- that is it! whoever is in the house (thieves, agents, president): (1) you can always kill those unconscious people in the house later (2) do not kill them, but rather capture them to extract any useful info from them (3) Red Queen is not anti-human per-se, so nerve instead of lethal gas saves life of Alice and agent. Hm, stretched, but ok.